# Testing a password with ASP.NET Core Identity Model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I need to perform some async tasks before creating the user account on a registration page, and I need to validate the password before I do those. How to I apply the validators without creating the user account?

Unless it's iterating through the `userManager.PasswordValidators` collection, but I don't have the `User` object to do so:

```
foreach (var validator in userManager.PasswordValidators)
{
    var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(userManager, new User(), registerDTO.Password);
    if (!result.Succeeded) return BadRequest(result.Errors.First().Description);
}
```

(I thought there would be an answer for this but couldn't find it.)

Comment: Do you mean not to create a user and then verify the identity model test password?

Comment: I need to (amongst other things) validate the password first, then create a user on a remote system, and then create a user in the local system. So all the validation needs to happen before the remote account is created, otherwise if that succeeds but (eg) the password is not strong enough, then the second part (local system) fails but leaves me with a login on the remote system.